# How to send same php filled form to client also

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

How to send same PHP filled form to client also?

Like the below code sent the file to website owner in HTML/PHP forms

```
$to = "owner@gmail.com";
```

Now how to add client also here like

```
$to = "owner@gmail.com,$email";
```

Or what?

Comment: I've not understand... Please explain better your issue. Where are you stock the emails ? If there are in array, you can use implode function ... but we can't help you for the moment

Comment: In my website i want to create a php form then sent it to my email id and the customer email id also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$field_email = "sender@mail.com"

$to = "owner@site.com, $feild_email ";
$subject = "Subject"
$message = "MESSAGE";

mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

Comment: Thanks its work i do like
$field_email ='.$_REQUEST["email"].';